# SQL Server, T-SQL is there a faster way to substring the following string in my question?

Tags: sql-server, algorithm, t-sql, substring, performance

I have strings like

OPEN SYSTEMS SUB GR (GM/BTIB(1111)/BTITDBL(2222)/BTVY(4444)/ACSVTYSAG)

in my database under my GROUPS Column.

What I want to do is to extract the 2222 from that string. The code I am using is like that.

```
    SELECT 
        SUBSTRING(GROUPS, CHARINDEX('(',GROUPS, CHARINDEX('(',GROUPS, CHARINDEX('(',GROUPS,0)+1)+1)+1, 4 ) AS GroupNo

    FROM MY_TABLE

    WHERE

    ISNUMERIC(SUBSTRING(GROUPS, CHARINDEX('(',GROUPS, CHARINDEX('(',GROUPS, CHARINDEX('(',GROUPS,0)+1)+1)+1, 4 )) = 1
```

I need to fasten the above code up, by either changing the substring way I am using , or changing some logic. Can you tell me what things can be improved in my code ?

Answer (score 1):

If you are doing that often I would consider parsing the data on insert/update/delete via a trigger into a separate table (say `MY_TABLE_ELEMENTS`), and then SELECT from `MY_TABLE` joined to `MY_TABLE_ELEMENTS`.

You could, for instance use a [split](http://www.snippetcenter.org/de/t-sql-split-function-s3.aspx) function (splitting on "(", if I understand your code correctly), storing either each entire split element into MY_TABLE_ELEMENTS, or parsing out just the numeric part.

Comment: Yes I am doing that often, but the data is not static and changing everyday. So using a table won't help me. And I think that using a View also won't work, since it executes the code inside it everytime it is executed am I right ?

Comment: if you place a trigger on MY_TABLE, then it will have to manage changes to the parsed data that lands in MY_TABLE_ELEMENTS: i.e. delete and replace for UPDATE, delete for DELETE, create for INSERT.

Comment: I didn't know about trigers before, I made some research and have a question to you, I am putting data to my_table by copy paste. When I paste 3000 lines, that means 3000 insert exectutions. But one exectuion would be enough for me. I can cheat coding but I won't like to code it stupidly like a putting trigger for delete, and execute 1 unnecessary delete.

Answer (score 1):

You could implemenet a CLR UDF which implements [regex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163473.aspx).

Comment: I tried Regex before and it is really complex for me, can you give an example if that is easy for you ?

Answer (score 1):

A set-based implementation.

This is less performant than your code for single rows, but should scale better for larger result sets, particularly if you replace the CTE generating the dynamic numbers table with a static numbers table.

```
DECLARE @t TABLE
(groups VARCHAR(250))

INSERT @t
VALUES ('OPEN SYSTEMS SUB GR (GM/BTIB(1111)/BTITDBL(2222)/BTVY(4444)/ACSVTYSAG)')

INSERT @t
VALUES ('OPEN SYSTEMS SUB GR (GM/BTIB(1111)/BTITDBL(3333)/BTVY(4444)/ACSVTYSAG)')

DECLARE @chr_delim CHAR(1)
SET @chr_delim = '('

-- nums_cte generates a dynamic numbers table
-- replace this with your own numbers table if you have one
;WITH nums_cte 
AS 
( 
        SELECT 1 AS n 
        UNION ALL 
        SELECT n+1 FROM nums_cte 
        WHERE n < 250
) 
,splitCTE    
AS
(
        SELECT  SUBSTRING(s,n,CHARINDEX(@chr_delim, s + @chr_delim,n) -n) AS ELEMENT
                ,s
                ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY s
                                    ORDER BY n
                                   ) AS rn
        FROM (SELECT groups AS s FROM @t) AS D
        JOIN nums_cte
        ON n <= LEN(s)
        AND SUBSTRING(@chr_delim + s,n,1) = @chr_delim 
)
SELECT LEFT(ELEMENT,4) AS GroupNo
       ,s AS originalString
FROM splitCTE
WHERE rn = 4
AND   ISNUMERIC(LEFT(ELEMENT,4)) = 1
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```